# Zero-Crossing Detector Circuit for a PWM-Generated Sine Wave

Tags: pwm, stepper-motor, stepper-driver, zero-crossing

Given this PWM,

[image: PWM-sine]

How to detect a zero crossing **without** a dual-voltage supply? There is only VCC and GND.

---

I've tried using a low-pass filter approach, but the PWM frequency is not guaranteed to be constant: it may be anywhere from 1 kHz to 60 kHz.

I am trying not to sink too much current or use an LRC filter which may affect the original waveform.

Here is what I've tried, but some crossings are missed, and spikes occur. LM358 is what I happen to have on hand.

[image: What I've tried]

S2 and S3 are from the PWM source without a common GND. Note, the source of the PWM signal is from a stepper motor driver: I'm trying to test various stepper motor drivers that do full steps, half steps, and microsteps.

Comment: Maybe the analog domain isn’t the correct place to find the zero crossing, perhaps a digital circuit to check for times when the signal has been low “long enough” to be considered zero?

Comment: You could avoid using RC filters (inherent lag) and simply rely on measuring on the `s3` side. On the `s2` side there will be the first half of pulses and, when that stops, at `s3` there will be the 2nd half, but not negative -- positive. It's the difference that makes them alternating signs. So, measure at `s3` and detect the first pulse that comes. There may be noise which may make the true zero-crossing have mixed pulses, and the first pulse, even with a clean waveform, will not come at a perfect zero-crossing but, you won't need bipolar supply; only a comp and a divider. One idea.

Comment: Or, if you have access to, you could measure directly before the PWM comparator in the control loop. That will give you the precise modulating waveform. This assumes an analog approach.

Comment: "*the PWM frequency is not guaranteed to be constant...may be...1 to 60 kHz*" Is the source using PDM then, not PWM? If the frequency can constantly vary during the waveform then it is.

Comment: @TonyM No. PWM. "I'm trying to test various stepper motor drivers that do full steps, half steps, and microsteps." --> The circuit is constant, the stepper drivers (and their PWM frequency) change.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen It's a good idea. I even tried biasing on side to ground instead of a center tap. Simulations look promising, but the noise in the breadboarding (parasitic cap and ind) causes false ZCs, so I'm trying to think of a more robust solution. Would love to stay in the analog domain if it can be helped (vs throwing a microcontroller and ADC at it)